# jquery, post multiple variables

Tags: jquery

I am brand new to jquery and trying to modify a basic script from php academy.

the jquery script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function get() {
    $.post('getpeopleinjobs.php', {
        postvarfname: form.firstname.value,
        postvarlname: form.d = surname.value
    }, function(output) {
        $('#age').html(output).show();
    });
}
</script>
```

and my form code is:

```
    <form name="form">
    <input type="text" id="firstname">
    <input type="text" id="surname">
    <input type="button" value="get" onclick="get();">
    </form>
```

This worked perfectly when I was passing just one variable and my code snippet was:

```
$.post('getpeopleinjobs.php', {
    postvarfname: form.firstname.value
}
```

I then tried to add a second variable with

```
$.post('getpeopleinjobs.php', {
    postvarfname: form.firstname.value,
    postvarlname: form.d = surname.value
}
```

It does not work now in Internet Explorer but interestingly enough it does work in Chrome?

Any advice for the beginner?=

Comment: Are you sure you mean to have that `d=` sitting in the second value? So, it should read `$.post ('getpeopleinjobs.php',{postvarfname: form.firstname.value,postvarlname: form.surname.value}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have the concept down correctly but there appears to be a minor mistake

```
//Posted Code
$.post ('getpeopleinjobs.php',{postvarfname: form.firstname.value,postvarlname: form.d=surname.value}
// Fixed Code
$.post ('getpeopleinjobs.php',{postvarfname: form.firstname.value, postvarlname: form.surname.value}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have a typo in your `post` code:

```
$.post('getpeopleinjobs.php',{
    postvarfname: form.firstname.value,
    postvarlname: form.surname.value
}, function () { /* ... */ });
```

Should work fine.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you have an issue in your script.  Remove the `=` sign:

```
$.post ('getpeopleinjobs.php',{postvarfname: form.firstname.value,postvarlname: form.surname.value});
```

You may also simply want to write the script as:

```
$.post ('getpeopleinjobs.php',$(form).serialize());
```

This way if you add additional fields to the form you don't have to modify the script.

Comment: Hi John, can you elaborate on the serialze function? will this send all form data to the next page? Thanks

Comment: Yeah, the serialize function serializes all children `input` elements into the url-encoded text string http://api.jquery.com/serialize/